# Build Keeps Failing

Tags: java, android

Good Evening,

I'm new to programming and trying to get project to run in android studio but it keeps failing and the design mode will not work because it hasn't had a successful build. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have in mainactivity.java file.

I've got other programs to run properly within android studio but can't seem to make this one work.

```
package com.example.jenna.needtograduate;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainTimerDelegate {

    private MainTimer timer;
    private RelativeLayout myLayout;
    private RelativeLayout authorizationContainerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout authorizationLayout;
    private RelativeLayout connectivityContainerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout connectivityLayout;
    private ProgressBar connectivityProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        authorizationContainerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.authorizationContainerLayout);
        authorizationLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.authorizationLayout);
        connectivityContainerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.connectivityContainerLayout);
        connectivityLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.connectivityLayout);
        connectivityProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.connectivityProgressBar);

        timer = new MainTimer(this);
    }

    //region: Obstacle delegate methods
    public void MainTimerDidDetectReachability(MainTimer timer, Boolean reachable) {

        if (reachable) {

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // perform if connection is available
                    connectivityLayout.animate()
                            .setDuration(250)
                            .alpha(0.0f)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                    // optional completion block
                                    connectivityContainerLayout.animate()
                                            .setDuration(250)
                                            .translationY(connectivityLayout.getHeight())
                                            .alpha(0.0f)
                                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                                    // optional completion block
                                                    connectivityProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        } else {

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // perform if connection is NOT available
                    connectivityProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    connectivityContainerLayout.animate()
                            .setDuration(250)
                            .translationY(0)
                            .alpha(1.0f)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                    // optional completion block
                                    connectivityLayout.animate()
                                            .setDuration(250)
                                            .alpha(1.0f)
                                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                                    // optional completion block
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error messages I'm getting:

```
Error:error: resource color/fadedBlack (aka com.example.jenna.needforgraduation:color/fadedBlack) not found.
Error:resource color/fadedBlack (aka com.example.jenna.needforgraduation:color/fadedBlack) not found.
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 9s
Information:7 errors
```

Comment: Make it easy for people to help you. The error message you're getting might be helpful to include with your question.

Comment: Error:error: resource color/fadedBlack (aka com.example.jenna.needforgraduation:color/fadedBlack) not found.
Error:resource color/fadedBlack (aka com.example.jenna.needforgraduation:color/fadedBlack) not found.
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:

Comment: I think the problem come from your your layout file. Are you using a color (fadedBlack) that does not exist in your colors.xml?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `fadedBlack` dosent exist in your project. Try checking in `colors.xml` under the `values` folder.